# Schengen visa for a student

Tags: schengen-visas

Can you give me all available options? I am a 20-year-old student. My friend and I want to travel to Italy. The embassy wants to make sure that I will come back to my country, so they want a proof like a house and a high salary. I run a website on the internet with 1,000$ a month earnings. Will they accept that? Or do I have to be an employee?

Comment: How far away are you from finishing your degree? The closer you are, potentially the greater the incentive to return. Do you have a summer job lined up for after your Italian trip, what’s your travel history like? Do you have significant savings in your home country from your 1000$ pm earnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's about demonstrating you have a good reason (strong ties) to return after your trip.

Different people have different reasons. If you are a university student, the desire to finish your degree is a strong reason.

Making money running a website is, I think, a weak reason because you can do that quite easily from anywhere that has internet service.